# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, nullreferenceexception, loginview

I am using asp.net LoginView to show different data to authenticated and anonymous users.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" Runat="server">
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Foo" runat="server" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Bar" runat="server" />
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

I then access these labels in my c# file like this:

```
Label Foo = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("Foo");
Foo.Text = "whatever";
```

The error I am getting reads:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you add your stack trace details as well?

Comment: It looks like it did not find your Label, try testing that Foo is not null before trying to use it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Well presumably at execution time, the user isn't logged in - so there's no control with an ID of `Foo`, so `FindControl` is returning `null`. You should either detect whether the user is logged in or not separately and ask for the right control, or check whether `Foo` is `null` before you use it. (You might want to consider renaming your local variable to `foo` to be more in tune with C# conventions, too.)

Comment: how are you not a C# MVP for life? Really, Microsoft needs to bestow the lifetime achievement award in C# for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Label Foo = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("Foo");
if(Foo != null)
{
    Foo.Text = "whatever";
}
```

Now you will not get the error, but if `Foo` is null, then your label's text will not update. You need to determine why it cannot find the `Label` named "Foo".

Comment: Isnt checking for null is strange here? How will there not be a control named Foo if you created one?

Comment: @AndersLindén - because there are two different templates; `LoggedInTemplate` and `AnonymousTemplate`, so there is a possibility that the `Foo` label is not there, because if the `AnonymousTemplate` is active, then the `Bar` label would exist and the `Foo` label would not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for nulls:

```
object labelObj = LoginView1.FindControl("Foo")
if(labelObj != null)
{
    Label Foo = (Label)labelObj;
    if(Foo.Text!=null)
        Foo.Text="whatever";
}
```

Comment: Not very efficient. FindControl() result should be cached so you don't need to call it twice.